# Login button and inputs fields aren't work in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, fragment

First of all, I wanna say sorry about my English.

I am trying to build my first android application using android studio. I created the main page containing two taps one for login activity and the other one for the About section.
what I did exactly was create the Login activity for the fragments to hold the tabs and the basic design and one layout only without the java file for the about_tab_fragment section and finally the login_tab activity.

the problem is that I can not get the input data from the view and no action happened when I click on the login button.**(and there is no error in the Run).**

and this is my code:

> Login activity (Layout)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Login">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:src="@drawable/login_header"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent=".27"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent=".78"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1"
        android:background="@drawable/desigen_for_login_page"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/view_pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0"
            app:layout_constraintHeight_percent=".7"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tab_layout"/>

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/desigen_for_login_page"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab_google"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
            android:src="@drawable/google_img"
            android:elevation="35dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view_pager" />

        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab_facebook"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
            android:src="@drawable/facebook_img"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:elevation="35dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/fab_google"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view_pager" />

        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab_insta"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
            android:src="@drawable/insta_img"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:elevation="35dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/fab_google"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view_pager" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

> Login activity (Java)

```
    public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {

    TabLayout tabLayout;
    ViewPager viewPager;
    FloatingActionButton facebook,google,instagram;
    float v = 0;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        viewPager = findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        facebook = findViewById(R.id.fab_facebook);
        google = findViewById(R.id.fab_google);
        instagram = findViewById(R.id.fab_insta);


        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Login"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("About"));
        tabLayout.setTabGravity(tabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

        final LoginAdapterClass adapter = new LoginAdapterClass(getSupportFragmentManager(),this,tabLayout.getTabCount());
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));


        //For animations
        facebook.setTranslationY(300);
        google.setTranslationY(300);
        instagram.setTranslationY(300);
        tabLayout.setTranslationY(300);

        facebook.setAlpha(v);
        google.setAlpha(v);
        instagram.setAlpha(v);
        tabLayout.setAlpha(v);

        facebook.animate().translationY(0).alpha(1).setDuration(1000).setStartDelay(400).start();
        google.animate().translationY(0).alpha(1).setDuration(1000).setStartDelay(600).start();
        instagram.animate().translationY(0).alpha(1).setDuration(1000).setStartDelay(800).start();
        tabLayout.animate().translationY(0).alpha(1).setDuration(1000).setStartDelay(100).start();

    }
}
```

> about_tab_fragment (layout)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="About"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

> Login_tab (Layout)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".LoginTab">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/email"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="92dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_inputs"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/custom_email_icon"
        android:drawablePadding="12dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Email Address"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:paddingStart="12dp"
        android:paddingEnd="12dp"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:paddingStart="12dp"
        android:paddingEnd="12dp"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_inputs"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/custom_lock_icon"
        android:drawablePadding="12dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.8"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/email" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/loginBtn"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Login"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.758"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.8" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/forgetPassword"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Forget Password"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/password"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/password" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

> My problem occurs here:
> I can not take the text from the inputs email and password plus that I can not add event to the    loginBtn. I tried to put Toast in the On Click Listener but nothing happened.
> Login_tab (Java)

```
    public class LoginTab extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText emailLogin,passwordLogin;
    Button loginBtn;
    TextView forgetPassword;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login_tab);

        emailLogin = findViewById(R.id.email);
        passwordLogin = findViewById(R.id.password);
        loginBtn = findViewById(R.id.loginBtn);
        forgetPassword = findViewById(R.id.forgetPassword);

        loginBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
              Toast.makeText(Login.this,"This is the login button",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                if(emailLogin.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
                    emailLogin.setError("Email is required");
                    return;
                }
                if(passwordLogin.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
                    passwordLogin.setError("Password is required");
                    return;
                }
            }
        });

    }
}
```

> Can any one help me to fix the problem.

I did a lot of searches but I could not find any answer.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't get your question, the code inside `loginBtn.setOnClickListener` does not want to execute or what ?

Comment: yes the code does not want to execute. but I found the problem. thanks for your help @MouaadAbdelghafourAITALI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.
the problem because I have to put the action in the class loginTab that extends Fragment not AppCompatActivity.

```
public class LoginTabFragment extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle saveInstanceState){
    ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_login_tab,container,false);
    Button b =  root.findViewById(R.id.loginBtn);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(root.getContext(), "This is the Login button....",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
    return root;
}
}
```